# What is the correct word-order for the title of a study?

Tags: word-order

We have a study about the effects of overcrowding management on patient safety in the emergency department of a hospital.This management is based on a stabilization model.
Now I want to write the title of the paper, but a problem occurs. Which one of the following (or any more suggestion) seems to be more preferable?

> The effects of overcrowding management based on the stabilization model on patient safety in the emergency department: a clinical trial

or

> The effects of stabilization model-based overcrowding management on patient safety in the emergency department: a clinical trial

Comment: Such titles often employ a colon, but you'd want to rearrange the order: *Patient safety in the overcrowded emergency department: a clinical trial of the stabilization model*

Comment: You can eliminate "the effects of management based on" and make the title more succinct by setting the stabilization model as the focus of the clinical trial. Since you wrote "*the* stabilization model" I assume that model is one already recognized by your audience as a management model. If that model is a new idea, and would not be known to your audience, you should say "*a* stabilization model".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your titles are too long, they are almost a summary of your report.
You'll want to mention the *keywords* (think word search).

The key points seem to be

> overcrowding management
>   modelling
>   emergency care

Alternative titles might be

> Overcrowding Management: A Stabilisation Model
>   Overcrowding Management in Emergency Care
>   Overcrowding Management in Emergency Care: A Stabilisation Model
>
> A Stabilisation Model for Overcrowding Management
>   A Stabilisation Model for Overcrowding Management in Emergency Care
>
> Clinical Experience of Overcrowding Management

Many of the details of a research paper are quickly spelled out in the summary just after the title.

Answer (score 0):

Both examples are painfully long and complex, making them difficult to comprehend in a single sentence. I think a better title would break the detail down:

The effects of overcrowding management on patient safety in the emergency department:  a clinical trial based on the stabilization model.